# Access env variable with Java and Github Action

Tags: java, github-actions

### Introduction

Currently, I'm trying to develop a project that connects to a website.
This project uses Java with Playwright.

And I store the login and password in the environment variable.

These credentials are used to execute the tests of the project.

To store these variable to GitHub Action I used this:

[image: Environement variable of the GitHub repositry]

### Problem

When I execute the tests locally I don't have any problem, but when I execute the tests in GitHub Actions they didn't have any variable environment.

### Question

Does someone know how we can use [`System::getenv`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#getenv(java.lang.String)) with GitHub Action ?

Comment: "Environment secrets" doesn't mean "these secrets are set in the environment", it's "[these secrets are only available in workflow jobs that reference this specific environment](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment#environment-secrets)". You have to reference them in any case using the [`secrets` context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#secrets-context), for example via `${{ secrets.TEST_PASSWORD }}`. For more specific advice, you have to show the relevant part of your workflow file.

Comment: If I want to access these values in code? eg - I want to access GITHUB_RUN_ATTEMPT and GITHUB_RUN_ID inside code where I use this to create a unique queue name along with uuid @BenjaminW.

Comment: Those *are* environment variables, and they're accessible as `$GITHUB_RUN_ATTEMPT` and `$GITHUB_RUN_ID`, or in the `github` context as `${{ github.run_id }}` and `${{ github.run_attempt }}`. That's different from accessing secrets.